# Mapping Generic Hub

Tags: signalr, .net-6.0

I want to register a Hub that has an interface, but I cannot map `IHub<T>` to `IHub`

```
app.MapHub<LairageHub>(HubConstants.LairageHub);
```

code for class:

```
public sealed class LairageHub : Hub<ILairageHub> {}
```

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0311  The type
> 'Marel.Lairage.Innova.Models.SignalR.Hubs.LairageHub' cannot be used
> as type parameter 'THub' in the generic type or method
> 'HubEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHub(IEndpointRouteBuilder,
> string)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Marel.Lairage.Innova.Models.SignalR.Hubs.LairageHub' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub'.   Marel.Lairage.Innova.UI.Blazor  C:\Users\cornelis.dejager\source\repos\Marel.Lairage2\Marel.Lairage2.UI.Blazor\Program.cs   62  Active